# How can I display masked account number on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, masking

I have an account number which is masked on initial display. When user hover over the account number I want to display the number. As of now value is hardcoded.

Project uses html, jquery, js

How can I achieve this functionality?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Account Number </td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="4xxx763"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data attributes, you can store the account number and partial account number and pull them back in event handlers.

```js
let acctnumber = document.querySelector(".acct-number");

acctnumber.value = acctnumber.getAttribute("data-partial")

acctnumber.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  acctnumber.value = acctnumber.getAttribute("data-acct")
});

acctnumber.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  acctnumber.value = acctnumber.getAttribute("data-partial")
});
```

```html
<input class="acct-number" type="text" data-partial="4xxx763" data-acct="4123763">
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, on hover the value should display whole account number

Comment: @TejasMehta I apologize. I have updated my answer

Comment: Since we are already nicely using data attributes, the values can be accessible through acctnumber.dataset.acct & acctnumber.dataset.partial